# How to fix ngspice simulation of Cree XLAMP CXB1507

Tags: simulation, spice, modeling, ngspice

I'm trying to simulate the 36V [Cree XLAMP CXB1507](https://www.cree.com/led-components/products/xlamp-leds-integrated-arrays/xlamp-cxb1507) ([spice model](https://www.cree.com/led-components/media/documents/XLamp-CXB1507-Spice.txt)) using kicad+ngspice.

When I try simulate it gives the following error:

> .model cxb1507 36v d is=6.15257e-19 n=32.22321 rs=9.82504 xti=1282.00581 ...
> Unknown model type 36v - ignored

If I delete the 36v in the spice model the simulation runs, but I'm not sure if it's accurate.

Aplologies if this is simple/obvious, I'm new to circuit simulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.model` card has this syntax: `.model <model_name> <type> <parameters>`. In this case, the model is `CXB1507`, the type is a diode (`d`), and the parameters are the list that follows. `36V` is not part of the syntax, so it's discarded, or gives an error. It's safe to remove that since it looks like it's meant to be a tag-like notation. Or you can add an underscore between the model and the offending characters, and it will count as a single model line: `CXB1507_36V` (don't forget to rename the diode using that `.model`, too).

Comment: @DuncanWither I already said that in the answer, but it's more of a guess than anything else. They may have forgot to add the underscore, themselves, or it's a fluke. Plenty of causes. If you think this answers your question, mark it with the check mark (but wait a while, someone may have a better answer). When other people will search for similar problems, they'll know that this question has an accepted answer.